# flutter firebase background notification not working on IOS

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have done all the steps and i am getting the notification when the app is in background but the function `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` is not called to process data.

This is my info.plist

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<string>NO</string>
<key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

This is my main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: false,
    badge: false,
    sound: false,
  );
  Eraser.clearAllAppNotifications();
  Eraser.resetBadgeCountAndRemoveNotificationsFromCenter();
  print('MAIN');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

and this is my top level function

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('TTEST CALLED');
}
```